# Equivalence of KEY_COLUMN_USAGE and TABLE_CONSTRAINTS in HANA

Tags: hana

I need the Equivalent SAP HANA Query for these SQL Queries

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

NB: `SELECT * FROM SYS.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` is working good to do same as `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`.

Comment: What did you try so far, the question doesn't show any research effort?

Comment: @yacc  I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Did you check sys.constraints system view?

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.CONSTRAINTS
```

Comment: There is any Equivalent Table for "KEY_COLUMN_USAGE" in "SAP HANA"

Comment: Hi umansankar, you can query Constraints system view in following format, I hope it helps. select * from Constraints where is_primary_key = 'FALSE'